# Como listar reservas cadastradas por um só administrador? (1:N)

Tags: c#

Eu cadastro meus atributos da classe Reserva, logado como um Administrador. Gostaria de saber como faço pra listar essas reservas cadastradas, por um específico administrador?

Exemplo:
Administrador 1, cadastrou 2 reservas.
Administrador 2, cadastrou 3 reservas.

Como mostrar na View, as reservas cadastradas?
Pois no modo como está o meu, ele simplesmente mostra todas as reservas. Não importa qual administrador esteja logado.

Método de Listar as Reservas:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Reservas.ToList());
}
```

Na View, utilizo este Model:
    `@model IEnumerable<FoodInTime.Models.Reserva>`

Classe Reserva:

```
public class Reserva
{
    [Key]
    public int ReservaID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o horário para reserva")]
    [DisplayName("Horário")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public string Horario { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o limite de pedidos/hora")]
    [DisplayName("Limite de Pedidos/Hora")]
    public int LimitePedidos { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a mesa")]
    [DisplayName("Mesa")]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "A mesa deve ter no máximo 10 caracteres")]
    public string Mesa { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o valor da reserva")]
    [DisplayName("Valor")]
    public double Valor { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Restaurante> Restaurantes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Como é sua classe `Reserva`?

Comment: Está logo acima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta usar o  Where do linq e passar o  id que  você quer.

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{ 
     return View(db.Reservas.Where(n => n.administrador == 1 ).ToList()); 
}
```

Comment: Eu entendi a lógica, porém estou usando Session no meu programa. Pois há vários administradores. Por exemplo, eu uso: httpcontext.current.session["ID"] pra pegar o ID do meu administrador. Porém o controller não pode usar isso dentro dele. Como eu poderia pegar o ID da sessão e inserir nesse codigo acima?

Comment: Só uma coisa, há um erro no código acima. De onde que esse administrador em minúsculo, será capaz de funcionar?
Quando passamos a letra pra escolher a classe, ele nem sequer aparece como opção.

Comment: Você tem que adaptar para o campo do seu modelo. Você não postou como ele é.

Comment: O que mando aqui pra você dar uma olhada?

Answer (score 1):

A primeira coisa que consigo reparar é que não há link entre suas reservas e quem efetivamente fez a reserva.

Será legal colocar uma propriedade na classe `Reserva` que criasse esse link, algo assim:

```
class Reserva
{
    // .. outra propriedades
    // ID do Administrador que fez a reserva
    public int ReservadoPor { get; set; }
}
```

Assim, pode-se fazer como na outra resposta, e consultar as reservas:

```
var reservas = db.Reservas.Find(r => r.ReservadoPor == IdDoUsuarioLogado).ToList();
```

Assim você terá todas as reservas feitas pelo usuário logado.

Vi também nos comentários de outras respostas que você está utilizando `Session` para manter informação do usuário logado. Pois bem, **não faça isso**.

- Sessions são alocadas no Pool do IIS: quando a memória do AppPool é reciclada, seus dados armazenados em Session são liberados;
- Sessions são de acesso exclusivo: Sempre que se realiza um acesso à Session, todo pipe de execução é travado até que o acesso seja finalizado. Então você consegue ter apenas um acesso ao Session por vez. Imagine isso com vários usuários conectados simultaneamente.
- Session não são escaláveis: Como ela é alocada no AppPool, se hospedado em servidores escaláveis, essa informação não irá ser compartilhada entre outros hosts. Então se sua app usa Session, não é possível escalar horizontalmente.

Por isso usamos Cache ao invés de Session. E também é por tudo isso que existe várias soluções de Cache no mercado hoje.

Só não esqueça que Cache é compartilhado por toda aplicação. Então, se for fazer cache de dados de um usuário, faça simplesmente `Cache["DadosDoUsuario" + UsuarioId]` e seja feliz.

Você pode usar o `System.Web.Caching.Cache` por hora, e se precisar realmente investir em dados em Cache, partir para um [Redis](http://redis.io/), por exemplo.